# What are CyanogenMod and MIUI based phones?

Tags: cyanogenmod, custom-roms, miui

Recently I came to know about some phones which are based on MIUI and CyanogenMod. I want to know if the meaning behind it is they will get lifetime updates from MIUI and CyanogenMod or something else?

Answer (score 5):

- **CyanogenMod OS** is a custom ROM derived from Google's Android OS.  It is available for large number of devices and delivers updates as nightlies, release candidates, betas, snapshots etc. Frequency of updates depends on the type of ROM flashed onto the device.
- **MIUI** (Mi User Interface) is also a custom ROM which is based on both Google's Android and CyanogenMod but has a home-cooked and customized interface developed by a Chinese firm Xiaomi Tech. It highly resembles Apple's iOS interface. MIUI is available for some flagship phones from popular brands.

All the devices running on CyanogenMod and MIUI gets updates very frequently than others. Updates occur over-the-air (FOTA). As a bottom line they are used as stock firmware replacements.

Comment: Well put (+1). Additional details can be found in our tag-wikis for [cyanogenmod](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/cyanogenmod/info) and [miui](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/miui/info).

Comment: @MANI I am talking about devices that have  tie up between device manufacturer and theses(MIUI & cynogenmod) and come in market MIUI & cynogenmod as stock rom. Also will they be updated until these communties(stock firmware replacements.) are interested in them OR until manufature pays them ? And if manufacture is not paying them then without thier support these CyanogenMod and MIUI roms may have stability issues

Comment: Don't have to worry about stability of the ROMs. They are stable and reliable and you will receive updates until the contract between the companies expires.

Comment: @user1917769 Here is some additional info for MANI's last comment. Your question is genuine about updates. Before I detail anything I should clear that "Cyanogenmod" is a community ROM only while "Cyanogen OS" is a proprietary ROM (based on former) by Cyanogen Inc. and serving as stock ROM in some phones. Both are usually referred by folks as "CM". IDK about MIUI though.

Comment: @user1917769 Anyhow, a community doesn't care for any contract between manufacturer and OS provider. It will continue to build and provide as long its developers are interested to do it. The quality of the ROM (stability usually) depends upon many factors like rigorous code review, multiple testing on devices, etc. Cyanogenmod community has acceptable standard for its official ROMs. Keep calm and flash them. :) On the other hand, a contract between a manufacturer and an OS provider (say Cyanogen Inc.) can bind the latter to provide a well-tested stable ROM for the device("OnePlus One" device).

Answer (score 2):

**MIUI** is made by the [Xiaomi](http://www.mi.com/en/) company. It's the skin, based on Android, they use on their devices like the [Redmi 2](http://www.mi.com/in/redmi2/). Xiaomi provides the updates to these devices. Not that officially they are only released in the eastern market, but I've read some news that they are expanding to the American and European market as well.

**Cyanogenmod** is the first, popular custom version of Android provided by Team Cyanogenmod. It's still actively developed and being released for a serious amount of devices, but his is unoffical for every device except the OnePlus One, but that deal is also over now. [See their website for more info](http://www.cyanogenmod.org/)

Comment: Another device that comes with cyanogenmod pre-installed is the Indian phone brand: yu yureka.

Comment: @xangua add yu yuphoria too

Answer (score 0):

MIUI is a highly customized UI that almost acts as a new OS giving you access to all the features of the latest android and many of its own features like themes and lockscreen activated music player and all with the same buttery smooth performance of early iOS versions. It is no surprise in only 5 years it is the fifth largest smartphone company and the largest in its home market.

Cyanogenmod is the next best thing a rom of stock android with all the limiters removed. It is very customizable within the limits of the android version it uses. Performs just as well as any android device with a few glitches since it is much more feature filled than stock. Some of its best features are 5x5 pattern lock and nightly updates.